# How can I get haml to recompile in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I added a div to my haml file:

```
%section.splunk
  .splunk_results Loading splunk data...
```

that will later be populated by an ajax call. However, it isn't showing up in my html file, even when I restart rails and navigate to that page. My [research](http://www.mail-archive.com/haml@googlegroups.com/msg05441.html) showed that it should auto-compile when I load the page -- why isn't this so?

EDIT:

The haml file is located at myAppName/client/order_details.haml. The HTML that it should be presumably compiling to is in myAppName/public/templates/order_details.html.

Comment: Are you verifying by looking at the HTML source? or the rendered HTML? (related: what browser are you using?)

Comment: I'm looking at both, neither seems to change. I'm on Chrome 20.0 (using inspector)

Comment: Adding HTML or text elsewhere in the same file / partial works?

Comment: in the haml file? no. in the compiled html file itself, yes.

Comment: Can you add the names of the various files (layout/template/partials), including how you're getting the HAML to show? (whether partial or template).

Comment: is there any more information I can give you?

Comment: HAML should **not** usually render to a file in `public`. Do you have this file in public, maybe because you use page caching or something? Basically, once a file is in the public dir, it will always be served as a static file (and Rails will not even know about it, much less re-render something)...

Comment: I'm not using page caching. I tried another solution -- renaming the .haml files to .html.haml and deleting the entire public folder. This does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

HAML files get interpreted as HTML files using the asset pipeline, [which requires that your file be in app/assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Additionally, the controller action specifies the file that will be rendered. Take a look at your Rails logs to see what file the action is actually rendering.